# MATE - Hide arrow on panel drawer icons

Tags: mate-desktop, panel

In MATE `1.8.1`, when I make a drawer on my panel,it always has a small grey arrow on it, which looks disgusting compared to my material design theme.
[image: Stupid Drawer Icon!!!]
How can I remove that tiny icon?